# how to navigate pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have to navigate to another page in asp.net suppose I have two pages i.e. Default.aspx and Default2.aspx how do I navigate between them ?

Comment: Are you talking about the user going from one page to another, or the page responding to some user action by transferring to another page?

Answer (score 12):

You could use [anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2) in your aspx page:

```
<a href="Default2.aspx">Click to navigate to Default2.aspx</a>
```

or make a redirect in your code behind:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Default2.aspx");
```

Answer (score 5):

there are many ways, here are a few to get you started

```
<a href="default2.aspx">go there</a>

<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnk" Text="go there" NavigateURL="default2.aspx" />

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn" Text="go there" OnClick="server_method_that_redirects" />
```

Answer (score 1):

On your server side codebehind you may also consider using Server.Transfer(..) instead of Response.Redirect(..).
Response.Redirect sends an instruction to the browser to change the page while Server.Transfer does it directly on the server side. Browse the web for further information about the differences.